# Getting "Undefined" error every time that I'm trying to render a JSON from a public API using: AXIOS, EJS & Node.js & Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, axios, ejs

I'm trying to extract data from a public API: `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php` to get a random drink name, but every time that I try to render the data from the JSON, I get an error message of "Undefined" and I get nothing rendered of the JSON data...

I use AXIOS to extract the JSON data from the public API:

```
const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
const result = response.data;
```

and then I use `JSON.parse(result)` method to convert the JSON into a Javascript object and render the data into my `index.ejs` file:

```
 res.render("index.ejs", {
         drink: JSON.parse(result),
          });
```

Afterwards, inside my `index.ejs` file, I use a `forEach()` method to loop all the properties inside the array in the JSON to render all the data to my `index.ejs` file:

```
<div class="cocktail-box"></div>
  <% drink.drinks.forEach(drinkDetail => { %>
   <li><%= drinkDetail.strDrink %></li> 
  <% }) %>
  </div>
```

**Whole `index.js` File:**

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const API_URL = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs")
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
        const result = response.data;
        console.log(result);
        res.render("index.ejs", {
            drink: JSON.parse(result),
        });
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.result);
        res.status(500);
     } 
});



app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

**Whole index.ejs File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cocktails Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cocktails</h1>
    <br />


<form action="/" method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="buttonDrink" id="buttonClick">GET A DRINK</button>
</form>

<p>Your drink:</p>
<% if (locals.drink) { %>
  <div class="cocktail-box"></div>
  <% drink.drinks.forEach(drinkDetail => { %>
   <li><%= drinkDetail.strDrink %></li> 
  <% }) %>
  </div>
<% } %>
 

<script>
  function handleClick () {
    document.getElementById("buttonClick").addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Clicked");

    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Whole `JSON`:**

```
{"drinks":[{"idDrink":"12862","strDrink":"Aloha Fruit punch","strDrinkAlternate":null,"strTags":null,"strVideo":null,"strCategory":"Punch \/ Party Drink","strIBA":null,"strAlcoholic":"Non alcoholic","strGlass":"Collins Glass","strInstructions":"Add 1\/4 cup water to ginger root. Boil 3 minutes. Strain. Add the liquid to the guava, lemon and pineapple juices. Make a syrup of sugar and remaining water. Cool. Combine with juices and pineapple. Chill throroughly.","strInstructionsES":"Agregue 1\/4 taza de agua a la ra\u00edz de jengibre. Hervir durante 3 minutos. Colar. Agregue el l\u00edquido a los jugos de guayaba, lim\u00f3n y pi\u00f1a. Hacer un alm\u00edbar de az\u00facar con el resto del agua. Enfr\u00eda el c\u00f3ctel. Combine con jugos y pi\u00f1a. Rel\u00e1jate por completo.","strInstructionsDE":"F\u00fcge 1\/4 Tasse Wasser zu einer Ingwerwurzel hinzu. 3 Minuten kochen lassen bis sie sich dehnt. Die Fl\u00fcssigkeit zu den Guave-, Zitronen- und Ananass\u00e4ften geben. Einen Sirup aus Zucker und restlichem Wasser herstellen. Abk\u00fchlen. Mit S\u00e4ften und Ananas kombinieren. Vorsichtig abk\u00fchlen lassen.","strInstructionsFR":null,"strInstructionsIT":"Metti in una pentolina la radice di zenzero e aggiungi 1\/4 di acqua. Bollire per 3 minuti. Versa il  succo di guava, limone e ananas con le rispettive dosi dentro alla pentolina. Fai uno sciroppo di zucchero e acqua rimanente. Raffredda. Combina lo sciroppo con la pentolina. Mescola.","strInstructionsZH-HANS":null,"strInstructionsZH-HANT":null,"strDrinkThumb":"https:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/wsyvrt1468876267.jpg","strIngredient1":"Water","strIngredient2":"Ginger","strIngredient3":"Guava juice","strIngredient4":"Lemon juice","strIngredient5":"Pineapple","strIngredient6":"Sugar","strIngredient7":"Pineapple juice","strIngredient8":null,"strIngredient9":null,"strIngredient10":null,"strIngredient11":null,"strIngredient12":null,"strIngredient13":null,"strIngredient14":null,"strIngredient15":null,"strMeasure1":"3\/4 cup ","strMeasure2":"2 tsp ","strMeasure3":"2 cups ","strMeasure4":"1 1\/2 tblsp ","strMeasure5":"1 1\/2 cup ","strMeasure6":"1 cup ","strMeasure7":"3-4 cups ","strMeasure8":null,"strMeasure9":null,"strMeasure10":null,"strMeasure11":null,"strMeasure12":null,"strMeasure13":null,"strMeasure14":null,"strMeasure15":null,"strImageSource":null,"strImageAttribution":null,"strCreativeCommonsConfirmed":"No","dateModified":"2016-07-18 22:11:07"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Just remove JSON.parse()
```

```js
res.render("index.ejs", {drink: result});
```